# <input> Validation for email php

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement, input

I've got a exercise to make a , and validate that with php.
Why it don't give out a error message?

If I check the name only about the length then it works. And if I check the name only about the right character then it also works. Whats wrong by //Error check?

```
<?php
  //Values set?
  if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $errors = [];

    //Error check
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) < 2) {
      $errors['name'] = 'Please put in your name.';
    }
  }
?>
<p>Input your name</p>
<?php
  //Show Errors
  if (isset($errors['name'])){
     echo '<p>' . $errors['name'] . '</p>';
  }
?>
<input type="Text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use OR (`||`) instead of AND (`&&`):

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 2)
```

Comment: omg. Thank you. I was searching vor a long time. but it was only a consideration error.. :( Thank you :)

Comment: Mark as accepted answer so other users in the future can know

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 2) {
  $errors['name'] = 'Please put in your name.';
}
```

with the || operator instead &&.

Answer (score 1):

What are you typing into your Input-Field? And where is that E-Mail?

If you want to make an E-Mail Input Field, you could do:

```
<input type="email" name="name">
```

On top of that, currently, if you E-Mail your're typing in is at least 2 Characters long, the If statement will pass, since you are using AND. You should use OR like this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['name']) || strlen($_POST['name']) < 2)
```

Just as a notice: You could easily use the following PHP-Function to validate, if the Input String is an E-Mail:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false || strlen($_POST['name']) < 2)
```